# request.getParameter String value pass as date to java

Tags: java, jsp, date, oracle10g

In my JSP page I have a field which is date and when I getting as `request.getParameter("dateVal");` gives me

```
15-Dec-2012 12:21.
```

I would like to pass this value to my database procedure and insert/update into table.
How can I pass the value as `setDate` using `prepareCall` to database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step would be using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse it to a fullworthy [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util.Date.html) instance in the controller:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm.", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateVal);
```

Then you can just create a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) around its time in the database layer:

```
statement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, please note that `java.sql.Date` doesn't remember the time part. If you have actually a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` field in the DB and not a `DATE` field, then rather use `setTimestamp()` with a `java.sql.Timestamp` instead. This way the time part will also be stored.

Comment: Why is dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm'.'", it should have been dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss right?

Comment: That's not how you showed `dateVal`. It's `15-Dec-2012 12:21.` and not `15-Dec-2012 12:21:00`. If you don't understand how to use `SimpleDateFormat`, please click the link in my answer.

Comment: Why were you so careless with formulating the question? Anyway, you should now at least understand how to use `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.sql.Date` the right way.

Comment: I get date as `15-Dec-2012 16:36` then after `java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateVal);` I am getting date as `2012-12-15`. What could be the reason? Thanks

Comment: I do by far not understand your concrete problem with that. What exactly is the problem? The way how the date is formatted? Why exactly is *that* a problem? Just reformat using `SimpleDateFormat#format()` or `<f:convertDateTime>` during displaying the Java date object to humans?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18059/discussion-between-polppan-and-balusc)

Comment: BalusC Problem is after `java.sql.Date(date.getTime())` date becomes `2012-12-15`.

Comment: *Why* is that a problem? Perhaps you did a `System.out.println(parsedDate)` and you expected the original format as before parsing for some unclear reason? You shouldn't be surprised at all with that result. The internal format is exactly as specified in the `Date#toString()` javadoc. Just invoke `setDate()` on the statement with that object and don't worry about human presentation at that step.

Comment: I am passing to db layer as `db.setDateValuesCallable(3, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));` and `setDateValuesCallable` is nothing but `setDate(position,Date);` and datebase it is insert as 15-Dec-12. Thanks

Comment: That's fine. I still don't see any problem. The `2012-12-15` is [the default `java.sql.Date#toString()` format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString()) of 15 december 2012, exactly the same as the input.

Comment: Problem is I would like to have minutes and seconds which is originally in dateVal String as `15-Dec-2012 16:36`. Thanks

Comment: I changed to setTimestamp() with a java.sql.Timestamp and database datatype remains as Date. It is inserting with minutes and seconds. Thanks a lot BalusC.

Comment: Then the database datatype is apparently not `DATE`, but `DATETIME`.

Comment: Data type is of  DATE. Regards

Answer (score 0):

@BalusC 's answer is perfect. But as an alternative solution you can use the function provided by database to convert String to Date while querying. For example(in case you use Oracle),

```
to_date(date_in_String, format)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

`new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").parse(mydate);`