# How to read input type="date" to java object Date?

Tags: java, html, spring

I have so input

```
 <input type="date"  name="date">
```

How to read from this input to java object of class java.util.Date?

P.S. Date date is a field of my Bean, which I read so:

```
@RequestMapping("/updateVacancy")
    public String updateVacancy(@ModelAttribute("vacancy") Vacancy vacancy){
        vacancyService.update(vacancy);
        return "VacancyDetails";
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [request.getParameter String value pass as date to java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896295/request-getparameter-string-value-pass-as-date-to-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC - Binding a Date Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705282/spring-mvc-binding-a-date-field)

Answer (score 8):

You may receive date as text and then parse it to java.util.Date

For example like this

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date parsed = format.parse(date);
```

You should also check that received value corresponds to you desired format.

Comment: Anything like this for `Time`?

Answer (score 0):

[The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) says:

> value = date
>
> A string representing a date.
>     A valid full-date as defined in [RFC 3339], with the additional qualification that the year component is four or more digits representing a number greater than 0.
>
> Example:
>
> 1996-12-19

So you'll have to parse the parameter value according to this format. At server-side, you'll get the parameter value exactly as if the field was an input of type text, and its value was a date formatted using the `yyyy-MM-dd` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14052884/7074223) you should declare an @InitBinder in your **controller** that handles the parsing of Date objects from Strings:

```
/* put this in your Controller */

@InitBinder
private void dateBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    //The date format to parse or output your dates
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    //Create a new CustomDateEditor
    CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
    //Register it as custom editor for the Date type
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. In the DTO object, the variable linked with HTML was declared as String;
2. When transferring to the final Object simple parsing worked:

```
LocalDate localDateInFinalObject = LocalDate.parse(DateAsStringFromDTOObject)
```